# Error split string index and length must refer to a location

Tags: c#, .net, string

I want to split a string according to number (size) after deleting espaces , for exemple :

I have "1254k 698 77" size "3" , and my method should return :

125

4k6

987

7

Here is my code , i have an error which is pointed in the for loop with i = 12 ,  string index and length must refer to a location :

```
 public string Reshape()
    {
        string str = "1254k 698 7785";

        str = str.Replace(" ", "");

        int size = 3;

        List<string> ListFormat = new List<string>();


        for (int i = 0; i <= str.Length; i += size)
        {
            ListFormat.Add( str.Substring(i, size));

        }

        string output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ListFormat.ToArray());

        return output;
            
    }
```

I want to refactor my code , if there is a more efficient method to do it.

What would be the problem?
I

Comment: @Llama: No Llama, what I actually see is a buggy code. I don't believe it is working. Take a look at the loop section.

Comment: @Transcendent My bad. I apparently missed that and only saw the "is there a more efficient method to do it" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following shorter version.
After removing the white spaces, we run a for loop to iterate over the formatted input. By incrementing the counter with the desired chunk size, we can safely traverse the string by stepping at the beginning of each chunk. We use the `String.Substring()` method to cut the chunks at the desired size. The `Math.Min()` method is used to determine whether there are enough characters to take. When the characters are less than the desired size, the `Substring()` will return whatever is left from the input (in your case, that is the last "7").

```
public string Reshape(string input, int size)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();

        input = input.Replace(" ", "");

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += size)
        {
            result.AppendLine(input.Substring(i, Math.Min(size, input.Length - i)));
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Also please do have in mind that this should probably perform a bit slower than @mecab95's solution since we will be calling the `Math.Min()` method for each substring.

Answer (score 1):

You must calculate how many characters are remaining in each iteration. The first argument of the `SubString` method actually means `offset` and the second means `take`. That said; if you do not have enough characters matching the offset and take in your string, you will then run into an error.

Comment: Thank u , see my answer , i have changed the method

Answer (score 1):

What i have changed in my code , but i feel that we can refactor this method:

```
public string Reshape()
    {
        string str = "1254k 698 77";
        str = str.Replace(" ", "");
        int size = 3;
        int RemainString = str.Length;
        StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i <= str.Length; i += size)
        {
            if (RemainString >= size)
            {
                Result.AppendLine(str.Substring(i, size));
                RemainString -= size;
            }
            else if (RemainString != 0)
            {
                Result.AppendLine(str.Substring(i, RemainString));
                RemainString = 0;
            }
        }
        return Result.ToString();
    }
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/NYSP68836)

Answer (score 1):

On the efficiency and refactoring side of things, I present this solution.

You should be able to construct the result with a maximum of two passes like so:

```cs
string input = "1254k 698 7785";
int size = 3;
string spacer = Environment.NewLine;
// Assuming no characters are space, then there should be (length - size) / size spaces between
// so the total size should be length + (spacer count * spacer length)
int maxResultSize = input.Length + (((input.Length - size) / size) * spacer.Length);

// initialize the capacity of StringBuilder so that it doesn't need to be expanded during execution of our method
StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder(maxResultSize);

int found = 0;
int i = 0;
do
{
    // Skip through the empty spaces
    while (input[i] == ' ' && i < input.Length) { ++i; }

    // If we're at the end of the string, exit the loop
    if (i == input.Length) { break; }

    // If in the previous iteration we reached a block of the max size then
    // we should add a space before writing the next character
    if (found == size)
    {
        found = 0;
        resultBuilder.Append(spacer);
    }

    // write the character and then increment found and our position
    resultBuilder.Append(input[i]);
    ++found;
    ++i;
}
while (i < input.Length);

// Build a string
string result = resultBuilder.ToString();

// Write to console
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

In the first pass, we append each non-space character of the input string and the newlines we want to introduce.

The second pass is internal to `StringBuilder` in the `.ToString()` method, and returns the resulting string.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/PVE26581)

Comment: Thank u for share , what do you think about that https://rextester.com/NYSP68836 ?

Comment: @mecab95 It works, but `str = str.Replace(" ", "");` makes an entire pass through the string and constructs a new string without spaces. You're also appending a newline at the end of the string.